# How to add php code in joomla module administration?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I was trying to develop a joomla 3.x module. I am finished with the basic module development. I believe I can do that. But now I am trying to add a PHP code to administrate the module from joomla admin section. you can take an example as slideshowCK module. you can see there they used some javascript and php code to take input for slides. I want to do the same. But I am not getting how they did it.

If some one give me a details instruction about this. matter.

Thanks a lot in advance. Looking for ward to get a answer from the experts in here.

Cheers,

Comment: Try asking your question in a little more detail on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Form Field type for this. By this you can render PHP and JavaScript Combination at module edit screen in back-end.

For more details, Please refer https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type